# when im trying to use page break, it is not working inside <tr>,<tbody>

Tags: javascript, html, css, bootstrap-4, jinja2

Here is my code:

```
{% for item in child.items %}
      
             {%set ns.count = ns.count + 1%}
           
       
   <tbody style="page-break-inside: avoid">
   <tr style="page-break-inside: avoid">
               <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;border-left:1px solid black;">{{ns.count}}</td>
                <td colspan="3" style=" white-space: normal;  border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;">{{item.sales_description}}</td>
                <td style=" border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;">85177090</td>
                <td style=" border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;">{{item.qty}}</td>
                <td style=" border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;">PC</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">{{item.rate}}</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">{{item.qty * item.rate}}</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">0</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">0.00</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">{{taxlist[0]}}</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">{{(item.qty * item.rate * taxlist[0])/100}}</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">{{taxlist[1]}}</td>
                <td style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; border-right: 1px solid black;text-align:right;">{{(item.qty * item.rate * taxlist[1])/100}}</td>
           </tr>
           </tbody>
           {% endfor %}
```

If the row is breaking, then the row that is breaking has to be moved to next page. But page break is not working for `<tr>`,`<tbody>`. Please anyone help me out

Comment: Have you tried to place the `page-break` directive inside the `<td>`?

Comment: No its not working. I have tired it

Answer (score 0):

This should avoid page breaks inside rows:

```css
td, th {
  page-break-inside: avoid;
}
```

Note the accepted value here is *"avoid"*. Not *"forbidden"*, *"never"* or *"false"*. The page breaks are avoided, but it's not guaranteed to work in all scenarios. It largely depends on the content being paginated.

If you need more help, consider providing a *runnable* [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) using codesandbox.io or similar.